# Extract all document uploaded to sharepoint

Tags: 2013, document, library

I am a software developer with very little knowledge of sharepoint 2013.
Currently I am in the process of creating a software system that uses external system to index documents.

The problem I am facing is that this data needs to be consistent at all times with the source from which sharepoint presents its documents (the content repository/database?). For example: a user uploads a new document to sharepoint and in the ideal situation my software system would poll for any changes within the content repository of sharepoint, and (re)index the file that has been uploaded or delete an indexed file that has been removes from sharepoint.

I need to know how I can extract every document from sharepoint that has been uploaded by a user. the data structure does not matter in this case. I would really like to be able to automate this process from my program code in .net or java.

Is this possible?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this has been sitting here for a while, and in the meantime I found a solution.

Sharepoint offers a vierual representation of its libraries in the sql database in the form a the file explorer. in Windows based systems we can access this using a UNC path.

With c# or java you are able to access this virtual file system on a UNC path by mapping the UNC url to a drive. i managed with a java.io.filealterionobserver. but I imagine there are a lot of c# solutions for this as well.